# How to kill all unnecessary processes on Mac?

Tags: macos

I have intermittent issues with some process (not sure which, possibly WindowServer) hogging all my CPU and making my macbook unresponsive (2017 macbook running Monterey)

Since I couldn't fix the problem, I initiated an OS upgrade to Ventura.

BUT after downloading the files, it prepared to reboot by killing some processes, thereby freeing the CPU so my computer became responsive again.  At that point I opted to NOT go through with the OS update because I was then able to continue working.  However later, the problem returned.

My question is:  How can I kill all those extra processes the way the system did when preparing to reboot?

Comment: Instead of upgrading or, worse, "hacking" at the problem, you should consider a clean reinstallation.

Comment: Are you sure your computer is not infected ?

Comment: I ran malwarebytes and the scanner did not detect any malware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacBooks (I have 2016 MacBook) are, in my view, underpowered for recent macOS (Monterey and Ventura). The obvious underpowering is in CPU, but disk access and RAM are bottlenecks too.

Blindly killing busy processes is not the way to go. They are busy for a reason. If you kill some you will lose functionality.

If you are prepared to put in the effort, discover what each process is doing.  If you are prepared to lose its functionality, disable its startup. In most cases that means disabling its launch daemon.

Whilst I do keep an eye open for wayward activity, I have now got used to waiting after boot or wake from sleep for the CPU to settle down.  After that it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Spend a day or two with Activity Monitor open, where you can see it, set to View > All Processes & see if you can tell what's using most Memory &/or CPU when it starts to slow down.

Trying to selectively kill 'some of' 500 running processes is not going to be a fruitful pastime.

Comment: Well I've been doing that, with top running in a terminal window.  The process that hogs the cpu is WindowServer, but I can't just kill that process.